# Strange field index issue with SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx

I indexed a new table and did a sphinxql search:

```
select id from idx_Table  WHERE (MATCH('@(Title) Word')
```

Which finds matches.

However if I try the search field in the Select command:

```
select id,Title from idx_Table  WHERE (MATCH('@(Title) Word')
```

I get an error:

```
[Err] 1064 - index idx_Table: parse error: unknown column: Title
```

I checked the Title field and the matches are correct so clearly the index is indexing the field and then searching in the field correctly. So not quite sure why adding the same field to the Select command indicates it was not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify **Attributes** in the 'select' part, not **Fields**.

As a general rule, **fields** are matched in the full text query (the `MATCH(...)`), **attributes** are used everywhere else (select, group, order, filter etc) .

---

Edited to add....

So a solution is to make your `title`, into **both** an attribute and a field, so can be used as either. For strings its easy with `sql_field_string`.